# Auth with twitter on a meteor app

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-oauth, meteor

Is twitter authentication on meteor js's roadmap? If not, how can I implement it?

Comment: Why don't you ask the Meteor team directly?

Comment: did you check the auth branch in github ? there's already the implementation of weibo google and facebook you see the source code for inspiration...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mike Bannister (@possibilities) has been developing this oauth1 Pull Request against the auth branch: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/251

I believe it's progressing well. So it should be coming soon, I'd guess probably when auth is released into master.

Answer (score 0):

Auth branch was merged into devel branch.

Can check out directly from Meteor devel branch.

```
cd ~
git clone git://github.com/meteor/meteor.git
cd meteor
git checkout -t origin/devel
./admin/generate-dev-bundle.sh
./install.sh
```

These links may help you to implement code for auth with twitter(and facebook, etc).

[Accounts API](http://auth-docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api)
and 
[Getting Started With Auth](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Auth)(deprecated but still works)